# How to create a webhook in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webhooks

I have a project where I have implemented different types of payment, I'm working with the `Conekta API`, now what I want to do is implement the webhook in my project but I'm new to this and I do not have much idea of how to do it

[Webhooks Conekta](https://developers.conekta.com/resources/webhooks)

I have a method in my controller and specify a post route in my routes.rb

My controller:

```
class WebhooksController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token

  def receive
    data = JSON.parse(request.body.read)
    if data['type'] == 'charge.paid'
      @payment_method = data['charges']['data']['object']['payment_method']['type']
      msg = 'Tu pago con #{@payment_method} ha sido comprobado'
      ExampleMailer.email(data, msg)
    end
  end

  render status: 200
end
```

My routes.rb:

```
post 'webhooks/receive'
```

According to the documentation I need to pass a route to Conekta, but I'm not doing it the right way:

```
http://localhost:3000/webhooks/receive
```

[image]

How can I create a webhook in ruby on rails correctly? Any example? Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can not pass the `localhost` to Conekta because it will not be able to access your app via `localhost` (which means only locally access).

There is a tool called [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) which will expose your host to outside and provide a public host. You can try using it and test your webhook again.

Comment: agree. use ngrok and call public url. this wat you can test your local env.